# How to tell pandas_datareader not to round the values?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

How to tell pandas_datareader not to round the values?

for example:

```
btc_price=pandas_datareader.data.DataReader('SHIB-USD', 'yahoo', start_date,end_date)
```

The prices are rounded to 0.0 for all the columns, as the real prices are very small here.. todays' price is 0.000065..

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the options for the display format of floats in pandas: `display.float_format`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#available-options

> The callable should accept a floating point number and return a string with the desired format of the number. This is used in some places like SeriesFormatter. See core.format.EngFormatter for an example.

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.15f}'.format
```

or maybe `display.precision`

> Floating point output precision in terms of number of places after the decimal, for regular formatting as well as scientific notation. Similar to numpy’s precision print option

```
pd.options.display.precision = 15
```

Another way to set the option would be:

```
pd.set_option("precision", 15)
```